# Use parameters to limit number of rows returned in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table of addresses and need to select a certain number of records based on ZIP code. For example, I have 300 addresses for ZIP code "A" and need 30 random selections. I also need 25 random selections for ZIP code "B" from the same table. Is there a way to use a table to insert the parameters for the selection, ZIP code and number of records, in a query?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not directly to a query object. This likely will involve VBA and QueryDefs modifying query object. And since you want a different randomized quantity for each ZIP, probably a UNION query with each SELECT line filtered for a specific ZIP. There is a limit of 50 SELECT lines.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `union all`:

```
(select top 30 t.*
 from t
 where t.zip = "A"
 order by rnd()
) union all
(select top 25 t.*
 from t
 where t.zip = "B"
 order by rnd()
)
```